# How to search an array of objects in jquery

Tags: jquery, ajax

I'm using ajax to get this array of objects returned to me. I'm trying to check to see if user email matches the one given by user also want to check to see if id is not null

```
Array ( [success] => 1 
[data] => Array ( 

[0] => Array ( [id] => 1 [firstName] => Juan [lastName] => Laxague [fullName] => Juan Manuel Laxague [email] => julx@iloud.com )

[1] => Array ( [id] => 3 [firstName] => test [lastName] => test123 [fullName] => test test123 [email] => tes1234@mytst.com )

[2] => Array ( [id] => 4 [firstName] => Mike [lastName] => V [fullName] => Mike V [email] => jar_k@yaoo.com )

))

    $.ajax({
        url: 'https://url,org/api/users/',
        datatype:"json",
        type: "GET",
        headers: {  
            'Content-Type' : 'application/json',
            'Access-Token' : 'CWku8OSq0w'
        },
        success:function(data){
            console.log(data);

            $.each(data, function (i, item) {
              var a = item.email;
              var b = item.id;
                 if (a == "useremail@nn.com" && b != null){
                        alert("success!");
                 }
            });
        },
        error: function(e) {

            console.log(e);

        },
    });
});
```

If I do `item[0]` it works for one result. How do I get it to check every result in the array of objects?

Comment: why aren't you checking this at server?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Inside of your result object (i.e. `data`), there's an object with a property named `data` which contains your actual results. You can iterate over the results using `$.each` as you are doing, but make sure you're iterating over the actual array that you care about (`data["data"]`):

```
success:function(data){
    console.log(data);

    $.each(data["data"], function (i, item) {
      var a = item.email;
      var b = item.id;
         if (a == "useremail@nn.com" && b != null){
                alert("success!");
         }
    });
}
```

You might consider renaming your results variable to avoid confusion around which `data` you're referring to.